# Jquery select element with . in name

Tags: jquery, jsp

how do I select a element which has a . (dot) in its id.

there is a element as follows

```
<select id="EmpFees.chargeCode" name="EmpFees.chargeCode"></select>
```

I have tried the following but in vain

```
$('#EmpFees.chargeCode')
$('#EmpFees\.chargeCode')
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `\\` because `\` is a escape character in a string literal

```
$('#EmpFees\\.chargeCode')
```

Answer (score 1):

escape twice

```
$('#EmpFees\\.chargeCode')
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$('#EmpFees\\.chargeCode');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$("*[id*='.']")
```

which means *"select anything that **contains** '.' character in it's id attribute"* as your question says.